# Why Magento can't load my Helper?

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, widget

My Code is generated by magerun, normally it works. I'm confused.

I have build an open GIT Repo for checking up my code:

https://github.com/webzellentOpenSource/ti-theme

Downside you will find the error in the system.log:

> 2016-11-13T11:14:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   include(Mage/Webzellentwidgetvideo/Helper/Data.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /html/mage-de-1942/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>       2016-11-13T11:14:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Webzellentwidgetvideo/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/html/mage-de-1942/app/code/local:/html/mage-de-1942/app/code/community:/html/mage-de-1942/app/code/core:/html/mage-de-1942/lib:.:/usr/local/php/lib/php:/usr/local/php/lib/php/PEAR')
>   in /html/mage-de-1942/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: Have you installed your module by creating an `app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml` ? This file need to exist in order for your modules configuration to be loaded in Magento. Eg https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/etc/modules/Mage_Captcha.xml

Answer (score 0):

Simpl solution - just use only the module without the vendor in:

```
<webzellent_widgetvideo type="webzellentwidgetvideo/video" translate="name description" module="widgetvideo">
```

That's all. Repo removed.

Answer (score 0):

Something additional - I got the problem again and was wondering.
I had generated the Module with magerun and there was an error:

```
<helpers>
    <webzellent_widgetvideo>
        <class>Webzellent_WidgetVideo_Helper</class>
    </webzellent_widgetvideo>
</helpers>
```

But I need:

```
<helpers>
    <widgetvideo>
        <class>Webzellent_WidgetVideo_Helper</class>
    </widgetvideo>
</helpers>
```